# Overlaying div and varying size images in a flex layout with vertical and horizontal alignment

Tags: html, css, flexbox, tailwind-css, overlay

I'm trying to have a div and an img overlay each other exactly (same width and height) so I can use the div to position some elements that should be markers over the image.

I only have a fixed height available to display the image, so I'm using max-width and max-height to scale the image down to fit the parent container.

The parent container is a flex so the image can be centred horizontally and vertically.

Using tailwind (but not relevant to the issue), I manage to get it almost working as it should be but their is always an aspect ratio of the image where something isn't quite right.

Here is a sample on stackblitz trying to show the problem https://stackblitz.com/edit/tailwindcss-wwat2v?file=index.html:

- The layout is split in 2, the left is the "main" view and the right is the preview with smaller images
- The main image should be centred horizontally and vertically
- A  should overlay the image so I can use it to position markers over the image.
- The marker image (cat snout) should be centred over the image

The expectation is for the layout to look as the first example in the sample but with images that can be wider or taller than the parent container. The ~closest is the last attempt but their is a margin to the image somehow.